# Seat reserving software: Drawing lots of Seats in C# instantly

Tags: c#

I'm building Seat reserving software using C# and I am confusing how I draw lots of seats instantly. 
I'm trying three way which is..

1. Using Usercontrol

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81727566/seatForm.png]

```
    public void DrawUsercontrol(int x, int y)
    {
        int space = 4;
        int SeatLimit = 165;
        int RowSeatLimit = 15;
        for (var i = 1; i < SeatLimit; i++)
        {
            UserControl1 ctrl = new UserControl1();
            ctrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
            ctrl.Location = new Point(x + space, y);
            if (i % RowSeatLimit == 0)
            {
                x = 1;
                y = y + 25 + space;
            }
            x = x + 25 + space;
            ctrl.label1.Text = i.ToString();
            ctrl.label1.Click += new EventHandler(label1_Click);
            panel1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        }
    }
```

2. Using "Panel" control

   ```
   public void DrawingPanel(int x, int y)
   {
       Panel myPanel = new Panel();
       int width = 16;
       int height = 16;
       myPanel.Size = new Size(width, height);
       myPanel.BackColor = Color.White;
       myPanel.Location = new Point(x, y);
       Label mylabel = new Label();
       mylabel.Text = "4";
       myPanel.Controls.Add(mylabel);
       myPanel.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
       // this.Controls.Add(myPanel);
       panel1.Controls.Add(myPanel);
   }
   ```
3. Using Graphics and draw Rectangle

   ```
   public void DrawingSquares(int x, int y)
   {
       SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
       Graphics graphicsObj;
       graphicsObj = this.panel1.CreateGraphics();
       Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, 30, 30);
       graphicsObj.FillRectangle(myBrush, myRectangle);
       graphicsObj.Dispose();
   }
   ```

I refer first option but it's too slow.
And how can I decide?

Comment: You could use DataGridView, bind it to DataSource. Each cell will represent a seat. And it's easier to manage.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are adding only one control at a time. Adding a control forces a full refresh (*software* GDI+ rendering is quite slow) of the parent panel (best case) and perhaps the whole form (worst case).

Try creating all your controls and adding them in one line using `Panel.Controls.AddRange`. This will only prompt one refresh.

You should also only add these controls when the form is first shown and when the number of seats change - it is an expensive (and *relatively* slow) operation.

Consider creating a `UserControl` for each seat so that you don't have to manage the *seat labels* and *seat borders* separately - this way you can just have one list. If you add the seats in order, the index of an item in the list will map to its seat number! You probably wont get a performance increase from this but your code will be easier to work with.

Comment: Another bits are: `BeginInit()/EndInit()` pair of ISupportsInitialize from Control, and/or `SuspendLayout()/ResumeLayout()` of Control, too. The former can speedup just about ANY mass changes in the UI controls (and is heavily used in InitializeComponent), but is sometimes tricky. The latter is safer and can help when you have to do many nontrivial shifts in the `Controls` collection that cannot be solved by just `AddRange`. See [SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx). Just dont forget to Resume it when you're done ;)