# graphical seat selection in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing a movie reservation system in codeigniter for my final year project. I want to create a graphical interface of the  seat layout when the user selects seat. There should be different colors of seats for booked,available seats.The interface should be displayed according to the show and screen selected. I don't have any idea how to do this.Kindly give me just an idea how to do this.What tables will be user and how will the layout be shown in the view.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your problem is like this? Click [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950946/seat-reserving-software-drawing-lots-of-seats-in-c-sharp-instantly)!

Comment: yes this but i am using codeigniter, i don't have any idea how to implement this in codeigniter..